# Azure APIM Policy to set backend service url based on environment

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, policy

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("xyz.prod.abc.com"))">
            <set-backend-service base-url=https://xyz.alpha.abc.com/lead />
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("xyz.uat.abc.com"))">
            <set-backend-service base-url=https://xyz.uat.alpha.abc.com/lead />
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("xyz.qa.abc.com"))">
            <set-backend-service base-url=https://xyz.qa.alpha.abc.com/lead />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-backend-service base-url=https://xyz.dev.alpha.abc.com/lead/>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Is the above policy the correct and optimal way to set a backend url for a Azure APIM API that is being newly onboarded?

Or is there a better way to do the same ?

Essentially, I want the back-end uri to be dynamically set based on the environment of APIM. If I have a backend-uri for each environment in Named Values ...can I use it dynamically and may be refine the policy to be more concise?

Comment: why not creating an apim api per env ? with this setup, subscriptions/products will be the same for all envs, not sure you want the same api-key for all envs ?

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, I want the back-end uri to be dynamically set based on the environment of APIM. If I have a backend-uri for each environment in Named Values ...can I use it dynamically and may be refine the policy to be more concise?

Yes, you can use the backend-uri stored in Named Values using the your policy with few modification.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("xyz.prod.abc.com"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="{{BackendUrl-For-Prod}}" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("xyz.uat.abc.com"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="{{BackendUrl-For-URL}}" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host.Contains("xyz.qa.abc.com"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="{{BackendUrl-For-QA}}" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="{{BackendUrl-For-Dev}}" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

Thanks **@Thomas** for the comment. By using this policy you can refer the backend URLs from Named Values but the subscription key and product will be same for all the environments.

If you intent to have the same key for all of your environment then you can use the above policy or else you can create separate the APIs according to your environment.